# How to reflect into internal and private nested classes in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, reflection, xamarin.ios

Environment:

- MonoTouch (6.2.1.201)
- Mac OSX (10.8.3)
- iOS Simulator 6.0

I am trying to write a test to make sure that the `NSNotifications` that I want are being registered with the `NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter`. *No problemo*, I thought. I have my list of `Notifications` and I can just ask the `DefaultCenter` what is registered with it...

Oh, wait, no you can't. :\

OK, well, I can reflect into my class and get the (private) list of observers I created and check in there. Except that it is a list of `NSObjects`, well, `MonoTouch.Foundation.InternalNSNotificationHandler` objects.

OK, lets do some inspection, `InternalNSNotificationHandler` is an internal class in `MonoTouch.Foundation` and it has a non-public reference to the `NSNotificationCenter` "notificationCenter" and the `NSNotification` "notify".

notify seemed like a good place to start, but I could not find any any reference to the notification name in there. Well, lets check the notificationCenter. There it is! In `notificationCenter.__mt_ObserverList_var._items[i].Name`. I tried reflecting into `__mt_ObserverList_var` (which is a `List<ObservedData>`) so I could just loop through them and compare the `.Names` to my list and make sure they were all in there.

```
var ifcType = typeof(myClass);
var observerField = ifcType.GetField("_observers", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
var observers = observerField.GetValue(null);
var internalNSNotHandlerType = observers[0].GetType();
// so far so good
var notCenterField = internalNSNotHandlerType.GetField("notificationCenter", BindingFlags.NonPublic); // this returns null
```

No matter what I do, it returns null. I tried loading the type from the assembly like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(NSNotificationCenter));
var internalNSNotHandlerType = assembly.GetType("MonoTouch.Foundation.InternalNSNotificationHandler");
// so far so good
var notCenterField = internalNSNotHandlerType.GetField("notificationCenter", BindingFlags.NonPublic); // this returns null
```

If I can't get to that, I can't get to the `List<ObservedData>`.

Why is this always returning null? Is it because it does not have Full Rights to the assembly? Is it even possible to get Full Rights in this environment?